# Calling an android method from Unity3D with a JAR plugin

Tags: c#, unity, android, eclipse, social

I am developing a game with Unity only for Android platform and I am requiring to share content of my game through an intent so I have implemented a JAR plugin according to several tutorials with this code:

```
package a.b.c;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;

public class UnityBridge extends UnityPlayerActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void callShareIntent() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        startActivity(shareIntent);
    }
}
```

The JAR is located at Assets/Plugins/Android with an AndroidManifest file which override the file created by unity, this is its code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto" package="a.b.c"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:debuggable="false">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|fontScale">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".UnityBridge"></activity>
    </application>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x20000" />
</manifest>
```

I just copied the manifest created by Unity and added this line:

```
<activity android:name=".UnityBridge"></activity>
```

... as you can see.

In the other hand, I have created a C# file in order to launch the share method of the plugin, this is its code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BotonCompartir : MonoBehaviour {

    AndroidJavaClass androidClass;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android) {
            AndroidJNI.AttachCurrentThread ();
            androidClass = new AndroidJavaClass ("a.b.c.UnityBridge");
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) && Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android) {
            androidClass.Call("callShareIntent");
        }
    }
}
```

... and I have attached it to a gameobject.

When I deploy the apk to an android device nothing happens, so What am I doing wrong? Any other suggestion?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Since you're overriding the Main UnityPlayerActivity your AndroidManifest should look like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto" package="a.b.c" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:debuggable="false">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".UnityBridge" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|fontScale">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x20000" />
</manifest>
```

And to successfully call "callSharedIntent" method from Unity you should get the instance of the Activity first and not only its Class as this is not a static call to a static method. Try this :

```
package a.b.c;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;

public class UnityBridge extends UnityPlayerActivity {

public static Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this;
}

public void callShareIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    startActivity(shareIntent);
}
}
```

And from Unity :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BotonCompartir : MonoBehaviour {
   #if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_ANDROID
   AndroidJavaClass androidClass;
   AndroidJavaObject androidActivity;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
        AndroidJNI.AttachCurrentThread ();
        androidClass = new AndroidJavaClass ("a.b.c.UnityBridge");
        androidActivity = androidClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("context");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        androidActivity.Call("callShareIntent");
    }
}

void OnDestroy(){
     if (androidClass !=null) androidClass.Dispose();
     if (androidActivity !=null) androidActivity.Dispose();
}
#endif
}
```